# Como pegar um objeto dentro de outro objeto no php?

Tags: php

Tenho um objeto dentro de um outro objeto. Como faço para pegar esse segundo objeto?
Segue imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$scope.calcular = function(valor){
    valor.receitaMediaMensal = $scope.receitaMediaMensal;
    valor.idempresa = $rootScope.idempresa;
    valor.valorTotalCustoIndireto = $scope.ValorTotalCustoIndireto;
    valor.valorTotalCustoDireto = $scope.ValorTotalCustoDireto;
    valor.valorTotalDespesasVariaveis = $scope.ValorTotalDespesasVariaveis;
    valor.custoIndireto = $scope.custoIndireto;

    console.log(valor);

    $http.post(url_mcp, valor).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);

    })

};
```

php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("../con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

print_r($data);

$valorPrecoVenda = $data->valorPrecoVenda;
$receitaMediaMensal = $data->receitaMediaMensal;
@$descontoPromo = $data->descPromo;
@$descontoFinan = $data->descFinan;
$valorTotalCustoDireto = $data->valorTotalCustoDireto;
?>
```

Comment: Se possível posta seu código. Fica mais fácil. Você também usou a tag *PHP*, mas postou uma imagem com *output* do *JavaScript* ?!

Comment: Estou enviando por JS, com angular e pegando por php. Isso que mandei é como o JS está enviando ao php

Comment: Código postado @ValdeirPsr

Comment: Qual objeto vc quer manipular? o conta?

Comment: Não, valor... Só preciso do valor.

Comment: Estou usando um for para pegar por posição, mas não estou conseguindo:

$qtd = count($custoIndireto);
$pos = 0;
for($i=0; $i <= $qtd; $i++){
  $pos = $custoIndireto[$i]->valor;
  echo $pos."\n";
}

Comment: `echo $data->custoIndireto[0]->valor;` Você pode usar `reset` para pegar o primeiro índice do array ou `end` para pegar o último. Ou ainda um `for` ou `foreach`.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @ValdeirPsr, mas como posso pegar esse dado dentro de um for, pois terei mais de um valor para pegar, entende?

Comment: @GustavoSevero https://hastebin.com/inugokerec.xml

Comment: Pois é @ValdeirPsr, já tentei com for, mas dá erro:

"<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/precificacao/matrizCalculoPrecificacao.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/precificacao/matrizCalculoPrecificacao.php</b> on line 45"
Essa linha 45 é:
echo $data->custoIndireto[$i]->valor, PHP_EOL;

Comment: Outra coisa, preciso colocar um varáveis diferentes esses valores, por isso tentei o for.
Com foreach não dá erro, mas não consigo separar os valores em variáveis diferentes.

Comment: @GustavoSevero corrigir o erro e modifiquei o exemplo #2. Adicionei um exemplo de como criar e capturar variáveis com nomes dinâmicos. https://hastebin.com/aqohokayoj.xml

Comment: Certo, valeu...

Answer (score 1):

No seu exemplo, você tem um array contendo 2 objetos dentro do seu objeto custoIndireto (0 e 1).

Para acessar o valor de cada um deles é simples:

```
$valor_do_0 = $data->custoIndireto[0]->valor;
$valor_do_1 = $data->custoIndireto[1]->valor;
```

**EDIT para modelo dinâmico:**

```
$array_valores = array();
$aux = true;
$cont = 0;

while($aux){
    if(isset($data->custoIndireto[$cont])){
        $array_valores[] = $data->custoIndireto[$cont];
    }else{
        $aux = false;
    }

    $cont++;
}
```

Dessa forma, irá verificar se existe o custoIndireto na próxima posição e irá pegar o valor e preencher o array `$array_valores`, caso não exista o custoIndireto na próxima posição, sairá do loop.

Comment: Sim David, mas quero pegar esse valores de forma dinâmica e não colocando [0] e [1], entende? Já tentei com for, mas dá esse erro:
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/precificacao/matrizCalculoPrecificacao.php</b> on line 45 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/precificacao/matrizCalculoPrecificacao.php</b> on line 45"

Comment: É possível fazer com isset, para evitar o erro. Vou editar a resposta, veja se resolve sua situação.